# I replied my opinion to his question

Tags: verbs

> I replied my opinion to his question.

Is this sentence acceptable?

I know that the verb **'reply'** is not used transitively except for **that clause.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not grammatically correct.

One does not "reply opinions", one "offers opinions" or one "gives opinions" or one could "foist opinions where they are not wanted or needed".

One does "reply to questions", but one does not usually reply to questions with **opinions**.  One replies to questions with answers that hopefully are polite, courteous, sober and well thought out.

I would suggest simply: "**I offered my opinion.**" or "**I gave my opinion.**"

If it is important to know that someone's question is being answered, I would add a prepositional phrase.  For example:

"**In attempting to answer his question, I gave the best opinion that I had to offer.**"

Answer (score 2):

> I replied my opinion to his question.

You may see this written, but it is not technically correct, no.  As you said yourself, reply verb is not used transitively and therefore doesn't have a direct object.

This form is more proper:

> I replied to his question with my opinion.

Comment: In the online etymology dictionary, reply means fold back. but this meaning itself seems to have disappeared  a long day ago. I suppose if the reply meant still fold back, it could have an object. Like this 'I replied his question with my opinion.'

Comment: But "What did he reply to you?" in the sentence what is the object of the reply. How does the reply take the object 'what' other than the example I wrote above?

Comment: @EvaristeGalois "to you" means you is the indirect object.  There is still no direct object.  In fact you usually see "reply" used together with "to" or "with" for this reason.  You can't *reply* something.  You can only reply *with* something.